# Spark Tesseract UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tesseract, javacpp

I have been trying to use tesseract using spark and having the below issue . I have tried using multiple versions of javacpp but still no luck .

```
val api: TessBaseAPI = new TessBaseAPI()
```

When I create an api here is the error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jnilept in java.library.path at

java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1302)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1043)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:935)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.lept.<clinit>(lept.java:10)
  at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
  at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:994)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:935)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.tesseract$TessBaseAPI.<clinit>(tesseract.java:3682)
  ... 62 elided
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lept in java.library.path
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1867)
  at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:870)
  at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1122)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:1302)
  at org.bytedeco.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:1021)
  ... 69 more
```

Here are my dependencies that I use

```
spark-shell --jars=Jars/Tess/leptonica-1.77.0-1.4.4.jar,Jars/Tess/tesseract-4.0.0-1.4.4.jar,Jars/Tess/ghost4j-1.0.1.jar,Jars/Tess/itextpdf-5.5.13.jar,Jars/Tess/com.lowagie.text-2.1.7.jar,Jars/Tess/jna-5.4.0.jar,Jars/Tess/javacpp-1.4.4.jar,Jars/Tess/jna-platform-5.4.0.jar
```

There are similar issues reported but java but could not find anything related to deployment in spark

Comment: add dependency ***tesseract-platform*** as well.

Comment: All the dependencies are added as per above

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bytedeco.javacpp-presets/tesseract-platform, I see tesseract only not tesseract-platform.

Comment: I have tried adding the platform as well . But no luck

Comment: Please set the `org.bytedeco.javacpp.logger.debug` system property to `true` and update your question with the output of that on the console.